# Cannot fetch javascript element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautifulsoup to fetch certain data from a site. I have fetched some data from the site but I am unable to fetch a javascript data which is in a pop up.

url is: http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#club/CD_T20

I have attached a screen shot and indicated the link having JS element.

[image]

When I click the link (marked in red  arrow), I find a pop up. I need to fetch the data in that pop up using beautifulsoup4 in python.

The screenshot is a follows:

[image]

Please help me out ...

Comment: When you fetch the HTML for that page from the server, the JavaScript isn't run. BeautifulSoup cannot parse what is not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page uses AJAX to fetch player details. The response is actually in JSON, so you could just replicate the behaviour in Python.

- The table cell has a `data-playerid` attribute:

  ```html
  <a data-playerid="CD_I271072" href="javascript:void(0);">Daniel Rich</a></td>
  ```
- The player ID is loaded with AJAX:

  ```
  http://www.afl.com.au/api/cfs/afl/playerProfile/CD_I271072
  ```

  and

  ```
  http://www.afl.com.au/api/cfs/afl/playerRatings?playerId=CD_I271072&pageSize=100
  ```
- The responses contains JSON data:

  ```
  {
    "playerProfile" : {
      "id" : "CD_I271072",
      "position" : "Left Half Back",
      "surname" : "Rich",
      "jumperNumber" : 10,
      "milestones" : null,
      "careerAverages" : {
        "goals" : 0.7,
        "behinds" : 0.7,
        "superGoals" : null,
        "kicks" : 11.3,
        "handballs" : 7.8,
        "disposals" : 19.1,
        "marks" : 2.8,
        "bounces" : 0.1,
        "tackles" : 4.0,
        "contestedPossessions" : 8.6,
        "uncontestedPossessions" : 10.5,
        "totalPossessions" : 19.1,
        "inside50s" : 4.5,
        "marksInside50" : 0.1,
        "contestedMarks" : 0.2,
        "hitouts" : 0.1,
        "onePercenters" : 1.5,
        "disposalEfficiency" : null,
        "clangers" : 2.3,
        "freesFor" : 0.8,
        "freesAgainst" : 1.0,
        "dreamTeamPoints" : 76.4,
        "clearances" : {
          "centreClearances" : 1.4,
          "stoppageClearances" : 2.3,
          "totalClearances" : 3.7
        },
        "rebound50s" : 1.6,
        "goalAssists" : 0.6,
        "goalAccuracy" : null,
        "ratingPoints" : null,
        "ranking" : null,
        "interchangeCounts" : null
      },
      "firstName" : "Daniel",
      "bio" : "<p>Daniel Rich is a high possession-winning in-and-under midfielder with a penetrating left foot and quality skills. The high-profile West Australian recruit received the AFL Rising Star Award in his debut season with the Lions and is now&nbsp;widely regarded as one of the most damaging midfielders in the AFL competition.</p>",
      "photoUrl" : "http://m.afl.com.au/staticfile/AFL Tenant/BrisbaneLions/Player Profiles/2014 - Profiles/RICH Daniel.png",
      "aflAwards" : null,
      "clubAwards" : null,
      "qa" : null,
      "sponsor" : null,
      "basicStats" : {
        "dateOfBirth" : "1990-06-07T02:00:00.000+0000",
        "draftYear" : "2008",
        "heightInCm" : 183,
        "weightInKg" : 84,
        "recruitedFrom" : "Subiaco (WA)",
        "debutYear" : "2009"
      },
      "careerStats" : {
        "goals" : 67.0,
        "behinds" : 66.0,
        "superGoals" : null,
        "kicks" : 1139.0,
        "handballs" : 787.0,
        "disposals" : 1926.0,
        "marks" : 285.0,
        "bounces" : 8.0,
        "tackles" : 403.0,
        "contestedPossessions" : 867.0,
        "uncontestedPossessions" : 1060.0,
        "totalPossessions" : 1927.0,
        "inside50s" : 452.0,
        "marksInside50" : 14.0,
        "contestedMarks" : 24.0,
        "hitouts" : 8.0,
        "onePercenters" : 156.0,
        "disposalEfficiency" : 69.2,
        "clangers" : 237.0,
        "freesFor" : 85.0,
        "freesAgainst" : 101.0,
        "dreamTeamPoints" : 7716.0,
        "clearances" : {
          "centreClearances" : 141.0,
          "stoppageClearances" : 233.0,
          "totalClearances" : 374.0
        },
        "rebound50s" : 166.0,
        "goalAssists" : 59.0,
        "goalAccuracy" : 44.4,
        "ratingPoints" : null,
        "ranking" : null,
        "interchangeCounts" : null
      },
      "yearlySeasonStats" : [ {
        "year" : "2014",
        "seasonId" : "CD_S2014014",
        "totalsAndAverages" : {
          "averages" : {
            "stats" : {
              "goals" : 0.0,
              "behinds" : 0.3,
              "superGoals" : null,
              "kicks" : 8.0,
              "handballs" : 7.7,
              "disposals" : 15.7,
              "marks" : 3.7,
              "bounces" : 0.0,
              "tackles" : 2.7,
              "contestedPossessions" : 9.7,
              "uncontestedPossessions" : 6.0,
              "totalPossessions" : 15.7,
              "inside50s" : 0.7,
              "marksInside50" : 0.0,
              "contestedMarks" : 0.3,
              "hitouts" : 0.0,
              "onePercenters" : 2.3,
              "disposalEfficiency" : null,
              "clangers" : 1.7,
              "freesFor" : 0.7,
              "freesAgainst" : 0.7,
              "dreamTeamPoints" : 60.0,
              "clearances" : {
                "centreClearances" : 0.7,
                "stoppageClearances" : 1.7,
                "totalClearances" : 2.3
              },
              "rebound50s" : 3.0,
              "goalAssists" : 0.0,
              "goalAccuracy" : null,
              "ratingPoints" : null,
              "ranking" : null,
              "interchangeCounts" : null
            },
            "player" : {
              "playerId" : "CD_I271072",
              "playerName" : {
                "givenName" : "Daniel",
                "surname" : "Rich"
              },
              "captain" : false,
              "playerJumperNumber" : null
            },
            "teamId" : "CD_T20",
            "gamesPlayed" : 3.0,
            "timeOnGroundPercentage" : null
          },
          "totals" : {
            "stats" : {
              "goals" : 0.0,
              "behinds" : 1.0,
              "superGoals" : null,
              "kicks" : 24.0,
              "handballs" : 23.0,
              "disposals" : 47.0,
              "marks" : 11.0,
              "bounces" : 0.0,
              "tackles" : 8.0,
              "contestedPossessions" : 29.0,
              "uncontestedPossessions" : 18.0,
              "totalPossessions" : 47.0,
              "inside50s" : 2.0,
              "marksInside50" : 0.0,
              "contestedMarks" : 1.0,
              "hitouts" : 0.0,
              "onePercenters" : 7.0,
              "disposalEfficiency" : 72.3,
              "clangers" : 5.0,
              "freesFor" : 2.0,
              "freesAgainst" : 2.0,
              "dreamTeamPoints" : 180.0,
              "clearances" : {
                "centreClearances" : 2.0,
                "stoppageClearances" : 5.0,
                "totalClearances" : 7.0
              },
              "rebound50s" : 9.0,
              "goalAssists" : 0.0,
              "goalAccuracy" : 0.0,
              "ratingPoints" : 495.3,
              "ranking" : 22.0,
              "interchangeCounts" : null
            },
            "player" : {
              "playerId" : "CD_I271072",
              "playerName" : {
                "givenName" : "Daniel",
                "surname" : "Rich"
              },
              "captain" : false,
              "playerJumperNumber" : null
            },
            "teamId" : "CD_T20",
            "gamesPlayed" : 3.0,
            "timeOnGroundPercentage" : 63.3
          }
        }
      },  // etc. 

      ],
      "seasonStats" : {
        "goals" : 0.0,
        "behinds" : 1.0,
        "superGoals" : null,
        "kicks" : 24.0,
        "handballs" : 23.0,
        "disposals" : 47.0,
        "marks" : 11.0,
        "bounces" : 0.0,
        "tackles" : 8.0,
        "contestedPossessions" : 29.0,
        "uncontestedPossessions" : 18.0,
        "totalPossessions" : 47.0,
        "inside50s" : 2.0,
        "marksInside50" : 0.0,
        "contestedMarks" : 1.0,
        "hitouts" : 0.0,
        "onePercenters" : 7.0,
        "disposalEfficiency" : 72.3,
        "clangers" : 5.0,
        "freesFor" : 2.0,
        "freesAgainst" : 2.0,
        "dreamTeamPoints" : 180.0,
        "clearances" : {
          "centreClearances" : 2.0,
          "stoppageClearances" : 5.0,
          "totalClearances" : 7.0
        },
        "rebound50s" : 9.0,
        "goalAssists" : 0.0,
        "goalAccuracy" : 0.0,
        "ratingPoints" : 495.3,
        "ranking" : 22.0,
        "interchangeCounts" : null
      },
      "latestPlayerRating" : {
        "position" : "MIDFIELDER",
        "roundId" : "CD_R201401407",
        "player" : {
          "playerId" : "CD_I271072",
          "playerName" : {
            "givenName" : "Daniel",
            "surname" : "Rich"
          },
          "captain" : false,
          "playerJumperNumber" : null
        },
        "team" : {
          "teamId" : "CD_T20",
          "teamAbbr" : "BL",
          "teamName" : "Brisbane Lions",
          "teamNickname" : "Lions"
        },
        "detailedRatings" : [ {
          "ratingPoints" : 478,
          "ranking" : 28,
          "ratingType" : "OVERALL",
          "trend" : "FALLING_FAST"
        }, {
          "ratingPoints" : 478,
          "ranking" : 1,
          "ratingType" : "TEAM",
          "trend" : "NO_CHANGE"
        }, {
          "ratingPoints" : 478,
          "ranking" : 24,
          "ratingType" : "POSITION",
          "trend" : "FALLING_FAST"
        } ]
      },
      "careerGamesPlayed" : 101
    }
  }
  ```

  and

  ```
  {
    "playerRatings" : [
      {
          "position": "MIDFIELDER",
          "roundId": "CD_R201401407",
          "player": {
              "playerId": "CD_I271072",
              "playerName": {
                  "givenName": "Daniel",
                  "surname": "Rich"
              },
              "captain": false,
              "playerJumperNumber": null
          },
          "team": {
              "teamId": "CD_T20",
              "teamAbbr": "BL",
              "teamName": "Brisbane Lions",
              "teamNickname": "Lions"
          },
          "detailedRatings": [
              {
                  "ratingPoints": 478,
                  "ranking": 28,
                  "ratingType": "OVERALL",
                  "trend": "FALLING_FAST"
              },
              {
                  "ratingPoints": 478,
                  "ranking": 1,
                  "ratingType": "TEAM",
                  "trend": "NO_CHANGE"
              },
              {
                  "ratingPoints": 478,
                  "ranking": 24,
                  "ratingType": "POSITION",
                  "trend": "FALLING_FAST"
              }
          ]
      },
      // etc.
    ],
    "pageNum" : 1,
    "pageSize" : 100,
    "pagesTotal" : 1,
    "ratingsTotal" : 61
  }
  ```

Use this to your advantage. AJAX Requests do require a `X-media-mis-token` token set in the request header; this is obtained by using a session (to track cookies) and POSTing to an API URL.

A sample script using `requests` library with BeautifulSoup would look like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_url = 'http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings'
token_url = 'http://www.afl.com.au/api/cfs/afl/WMCTok'
player_url = 'http://www.afl.com.au/api/cfs/afl/playerProfile/'

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(page_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
token = session.post(token_url).json()['token']

for player in soup.find_all('a', {'data-playerid': True}):
    playerid = player['data-playerid']
    data_r = session.get(player_url + playerid, headers={
        'X-media-mis-token': token})
    profile = data_r.json()['playerProfile']
    print profile['firstName'], profile['surname'], profile['position']
```

Last but not least, note that the token POST response contains a disclaimer:

```
>>> print session.post(token_url).json()['disclaimer']
All content and material contained within this site is protected by copyright owned by or licensed to Telstra. Unauthorised reproduction, publishing, transmission, distribution, copying or other use is prohibited.
```

Take that into account when you start using this data.

Comment: how did you get 'eac902a110977bc439a4453fe38a7490' value? and also the link 'http://www.afl.com.au/api/cfs/afl/playerProfile/'

Comment: @Anand: I looked at the requests made by the page in my browser developer tools. I saw that a direct request to those urls didn't work, looked at the headers the browser was sending and saw the unusual `X-media-mis-token` header. I extrapolated from there.

Comment: I understood your point. But the data which you retrieved is not what it shows in the pop up for a player.
example:
from the pop up Gary Ablett is a Midfielder, however, your output says he is a Right Back Pocket.

Comment: @Anand: I didn't go into detail what parts of the JSON is actually displayed. I picked a few sample fields, that is all. You'll have to do your own analysis from here on out as to what data you need exactly. It is all in there however.

Comment: @Anand: the `latestPlayerRating` structure is probably used; the specific player is listed as `MIDFIELDER` in that structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort ... :) keep in touch

Answer (score -2):

You cann't fetch this data because those data are not in present in HTML before clicking.
To do this use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html)

1. Load page in selenium
2. Make [click](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=click#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click) on element you want to get
3. Read data from "popup". This popup is marked with html id, so to get this in Selenium is very simple :)

Comment: This is not at all helpful for the OP's problem.